# Errors while compiling C code

Tags: compiling, c

I have found piece of C code which would be very useful for what I want do to under this link: [All possible combinations of characters and numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204069/all-possible-combinations-of-characters-and-numbers/330521#330521)

```
#include <stdio.h>

//global variables and magic numbers are the basis of good programming
const char* charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
char buffer[50];

void permute(int level) {
  const char* charset_ptr = charset;
  if(level == -1){
    puts(buffer);
  }else {
   while(buffer[level]=*charset_ptr++) {
    permute(level - 1);
   }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  int length;
  sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &length); 

  //Must provide length (integer < sizeof(buffer)==50) as first arg;
  //It will crash and burn otherwise  

  buffer[length]='\0';
  permute(length - 1);
  return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile it as it is suggested, I get following errors. Can anyone please help me to correct it?

```
$ make CFLAGS=-O3 permute && time ./permute 5 >/dev/null
make: Nothing to be done for 'permute'.
./permute: line 3: //global: No such file or directory
./permute: line 4: const: command not found
./permute: line 5: char: command not found
./permute: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./permute: line 7: `void permute(int level) {'
```

Also when I try to use gcc I get Segmentation fault error:

```
$ mv permute permute.c
$ gcc permute.c -o permute.bin
$ chmod 755 permute.bin 
$ ./permute.bin 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Give an argument when running `./permute.bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you initially named the C file `permute`; when the `make` failed, you tried to execute it with your shell, which resulted in all of those syntax errors (as the shell does not know how to execute C code).

In the second case, you hit the comment:

> //Must provide length (integer < sizeof(buffer)==50) as first arg;
>
> //It will crash and burn otherwise

because you did not provide a first (or any) arguments to the program. Try `./permute.bin 10`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, it looks like you saved the C code as `permute` and then tried running

```
make CFLAGS=-O3 permute && time ./permute 5 >/dev/null
```

Since there’s no `Makefile` with a target for `make`, it exited without error while printing the informative message,

> Nothing to be done for 'permute'.

As`make` did not return an error code, the second part of that command (`time ./permute 5 >/dev/null`) was run. Since `permute` is source code and not an executable binary, it was interpreted as being a shell script resulting in the following output:

```
./permute: line 3: //global: No such file or directory
./permute: line 4: const: command not found
./permute: line 5: char: command not found
./permute: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./permute: line 7: `void permute(int level) {'
```

---

Better instructions would be to save the C source code into `permute.c` and then run the following command to compile it (and link to required library files):

```
gcc -O3 -o permute permute.c
```

This creates `permute` as an executable binary which can be run, e.g.:

```
./permute 2
```